# Need all information of users, posts and comments in one MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

Here is my tables:

comments:

```
# id, user_id, post_id, message, date
'1', '1', '1', 'This is a comment bla bla bla', '2016-09-04 11:36:11'
'2', '1', '1', 'This is another comment bla bla bla', '2016-09-04 11:39:59'
'3', '1', '2', 'This is a first comment', '2016-09-04 16:35:43'
'4', '2', '2', 'Relax my friend', '2016-09-04 16:35:43'
'5', '1', '2', 'Ok, cool.', '2016-09-04 16:36:03'
'6', '3', '1', 'Cool bro', '2016-09-12 17:51:24'
'7', '3', '2', 'OMG! :O', '2016-09-12 17:51:53'
```

users:

```
# id, password, username, photo, background_photo, email, first_name, last_name
'1', 'rqwerr23r2', 'welkdic', 'img/Friends/guy-2.jpg', './../../img/profile-cover.jpg', 'test@test', 'Omarion', 'welkdic'
'2', '23rqw3rq32', 'McBrewk', 'img/Friends/woman-1.jpg', './../../img/profile-cover.jpg', 'test2@test', 'Hillary', 'McBrewk'
'3', 'wer23r23', 'jmorr', 'img/Friends/guy-2.jpg', './../../img/profile-cover.jpg', 'test3@test', 'John', 'Morrison'
```

and posts:

```
# id, user_id, date, type, message, image, shares, likes, comments_count
'1', '1', '2016-09-01 12:09:00', 'uploaded a photo', 'TODAY IS..... beatifull day.', 'img/Post/game.jpg', '0', '0', '2'
'2', '2', '2016-09-04 16:22:11', 'made a post', 'bla bla bla \r\n                     for bootstrap css hmtl js framework.', '', '0', '0', '3'
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
        FROM posts AS p
        RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
        RIGHT JOIN comments AS c ON p.id = c.post_id AND u.id = c.user_id
        RIGHT JOIN users AS up ON up.id = c.user_id;
```

I need all information about posts users and comments in one query. Right now in my result everything looks great but have a one problem with duplicate result of post table (marked in blue - position nr 2). I don't know why is that. [HOW IT LOOKS RIGHT NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfuTJ.png)

But it SHOULD be something like in next row position nr3 with NULL field:
[SHOULD LOOKS LIKE THAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv0Kg.png)
Already tried with 'group by' and 'distinct' with no luck :(
I need all comments users and posts in my result

Comment: Right outer join... Switch to left outer join, as most people find them hard enough to understand. ("main table left join additional data" instead of "additional data right join main table".)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Nope with 'left outer join' didn't help. 3 rows of my comments table was thrown away. Duplicate row is in the same position :/ I need all posts, comments and users

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts p
INNER JOIN
    users u
ON
    u.user_id=p.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    comments c
ON
    p.post_id=c.post_id
INNER JOIN
    users uu
ON
    c.user_id=uu.user_id
```

Comment: Result is the same as presented in my question.

Comment: This is right, because you have 2 comments to this post

Comment: Yes, but it's not the problem here. I have duplicate row in result. See my question